# Find specific file in 7zip archive

Tags: java, 7zip, apache-commons-compress

I'm using Apache Commons Compress to parse entries in a 7zip archive. I need to be able to find a specific file (e.g. "thisfile.xml"), I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it other than just looping through every entry in the archive.

The sort of thing I'm currently doing is this:

```
SevenZFile archive = new SevenZFile("chosen 7zip file");

for (SevenZArchiveEntry entry :  sevenZFile.getEntries())
        {
            if (entry.getName().equals("Sites.xml"))
            {
                //Do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
```

I don't particularly want to iterate over all entries in the archive, as there could be a lot of them.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: I assume you break out of your loop once you've found the file and don't waste time with any further entries?

Comment: Yes I would, I'll add that in

Comment: That's the best that I can suggest.

Comment: No problem, it's still useful and I have a feeling it might be the only way of doing it :D Thanks

Comment: If you could use Jar archives `java.util.jar.JarFile` has a `getEntry(String  name)` method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getEntry(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the best you can do. There's no more useful methods on this API that you can call, other than to loop through the entries and stop when you find what you want to read and process. Maybe try a different object API, such as the built-in Java ZipFile.

Comment: It probably won't be that bad performance-wise anyway - 7zip archives have the files and folders indexed, so even with hundreds of files it should only take a couple of seconds maximum (assuming the apache code is good)

Comment: Doesn't look like it, unless I'm missing something obvious

Comment: yeah it's possibly not going to be an issue, I'm just a pedant :D